# Algorithm to Find Top 10 Matches In Java

Tags: java, algorithm, match

I am writing the logic to find top 10 matches for a request (contains 8 attributes) against the User Objects List (a User Object has a value for each of the 8 attributes in the request). I have to find the Top 10 matches from this User Objects List.

What I am doing currently is:

1. Traversing the list.
2. Doing a match of Request Attribute with User object stored attributes. And IF 5  attributes match i consider it as a match and Update MATCH_COUNT to 1.

Like this I keep on traversing to find first 10 matches (5 attributes match).
I break the loop whenever I have the MATCH_COUNT to 10, even if list isn't traversed completely

The problem with this approach is the Untraversed User Objects in the List might have a match of more than 5 attributes but I didn't traverse because I had stopped.

So what do you suggest? This definitely involves traversing whole list before arriving at MATCHES, but I can't think of an efficient solution.

Comment: Sort the users using a comparator that orders the users by match count (descending), and take the 10 first elements of the sorted list.

Comment: It is what it is. Unless you have (or create) some sort of indexing into your collection's values then you have to traverse the entire list. This is actually no different from what a database engine would do if you gave it such a query. The result would be a so-called full table scan.

Comment: Is this part of academic work or professional work? Because you can get to the answer using the streams API in java. Something along the lines of `userList.stream().map(toMatchCountMethod()).sort(comparatorMethod()).limit(10);` Somehow I get the feeling that if the question were academic then streams api is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

- Traverse the complete list of User objects
- Keep count of the matches for each user object in a separate class which you insert into a list.
- sort the list descending by the match count
- return the first 10 if the list has more than 10 otherwise the complete list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) with a comparator that compares the number of matches of two elements. The algorithm runs in average time O(n), which is better than the time O(n log n) required for sorting.

Comment: First time I hear about quickselect. But it seems it's useful to find the k'th smallest element, and not the k smallest elements.